# Difference between "speed up something" and "speed something up"

Tags: phrase-usage

Both seem to be in common usage, but is there a nuanced difference about when one is more appropriate than the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're both forms of the same thing, a verb-particle idiom sometimes called a "phrasal verb":

```
  I sped the video up.  
  I sped up the video.
```

But if the direct object is an unstressed personal pronoun, *up* has to come at the end:

```
  I sped it up.  
 *I sped up it.　(ungrammatical)
```

And if the direct object is very long, put *up* first:

```
 ?I sped the new program for rendering alpha and beta particles up.  (awkward) 
  I sped up the new program for rendering alpha and beta particles.
```

Otherwise it's difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4):

There really is no difference; it is a phrasal verb (a verb consisting of both a "main verb" and a "prepositional particle", which combine to have a different meaning than the verb alone), and a phrasal verb can be joined directly or split, depending on the object.  The only hard and fast rule regarding splitting up a phrasal verb is that if you use a pronoun as the object, the pronoun MUST split the phrasal verb:

> *good:* I want to speed the engine up
>
> *good:* I want to speed up the engine
>
> *good:* I want to speed it up
>
> *wrong:* I want to speed up it

Otherwise, the primary guideline is, try not to put the particle so far away that it's hard to recognize that a phrasal verb has been used; see [this ELU question about splitting up phrasal verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77472/is-there-any-rule-about-splitting-phrasal-verbs) for more info.

Comment: Very great and nifty answer. I gave +1