# Usage of Phrasal verbs in a sentence

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Phrasal verbs are usually two-word phrases consisting of verb+adverb or verb+preposition.

Like many other verbs, phrasal verbs often have more than one meaning.

For instance:

1. **Back up** means *reverse*:

   > You'll have to **back up** your car so that I can get out.
2. **Back up** means *support*:

   > My wife **backed** me **up** over my decision to quit my job.

Can we switch the word order?

1. > You'll have to **back** your car **up** so that I can get out.
2. > My wife **backed up** me over my decision to quit my job.

Is there any hard and fast rule about the usage of phrasal verbs?

Comment: Note that you can't say *My wife backed up me* because if the object is an unstressed personal pronoun it has to go *between* the two words forming the phrasal verb, as pointed out in [the top answer to the original question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37407/126).

Comment: Could you explain"unstressed personal pronoun", please? I know what is personal pronoun but in this term "unstressed" is new for me.

Comment: ***stressed** = spoken loudly, given heavy emphasis*. As in *My wife didn't back up her mother. She backed up **me**!* Where the speaker could just as well have said *She backed **me** up!*, because when the pronoun is *stressed* it can go in either position, but when it's *unstressed* it can only go before the preposition (embedded *within* the phrasal verb).