# Pronoun as the indirect object

Tags: pronouns

In an semi-unrelated post, I saw where someone had said “In this case the indirect object is placed before the direct object because it is a pronoun.” in reference to the sentence “I gave him the book with the red cover while you were out of town.” He said, “Had it been a noun phrase, it would be placed after the direct object:
‘I gave the book to my dad.’”

Is this correct? I do not understand.

P.s. I didn’t take the suggested question link because this is exactly using the split phrasal verb. Therefore, I am asking something different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "speed up something" and "speed something up"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37403/difference-between-speed-up-something-and-speed-something-up) You can *speed **something** up* or *speed up **something***, and you can also *speed **it** up*. But idiomatically you can't *speed up **it*** (the pronoun can "split" the phrasal verb, but can't come *after* it).

Comment: Not a duplicate

Comment: You seem to be very specifically asking about contexts where a pronoun *can't be* or *(isn't usually)* used, but where no such restriction occurs with "ordinary" (or "proper") nouns. There's only an extremely weak modern tendency favouring prepositionless *I gave John the book* over *I gave **to** John the book*, but it's pretty solid that none of us say say things like *I gave John it* (whereas many of us *do* happily say *I gave him it*). I think the underlying principle are the same with a truly phrasal verb like ***to speed up*** as they are with a collocation like ***to give to***..

Comment: No, because you can also say: I have my dad the book.

Answer (score 1):

All are idiomatic except for the last two sentences.

> I gave John the book.
>
> I gave the book to John.
>
> I gave him the book.
>
> I gave the book to him.
>
> I gave the book him. <sup>NO</sup>
>
> I gave the book John. <sup>NO</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason for that person’s saying of such a rule? Is there any validity at all to it. He also says “first the Direct Object, then the Indirect Object unless it is pronominalised (in that case it precedes the Direct Object), and finally the adverbial complements.”

Comment: I would need to see the full context where that advice was given.  By **pronominalized** perhaps what was meant was "a pronoun in the objective case *without a preposition*", as in #3 above.

Comment: It is sander’s post, here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65016/order-of-prepositions#_=_

Comment: I am actually on my way out the door. Since it's a long post I'll have to read it later. But skimming it, it seems like sound advice. Read it more closely.

Comment: @AllexKramer: Note that although we wouldn't *usually* include the preposition in constructions such as *I gave **to** my dad the book*, this isn't actually ungrammatical (almost certainly it was more common to include it in the past, to the extent that the indirect object was ever likely to have been specified *before* the direct object - which was never particularly likely anyway).

Comment: For the most part, it is. That is just throwing me off. I had to have read it ten times now.

Comment: What he says is this *Complements normally immediately follow the verb. They stick to the SVC sentence structure (Subject-Verb-Complement): first the Direct Object, then the Indirect Object unless it is pronominalised (in that case it precedes the Direct Object), and finally the adverbial complements.*

Comment: I’m not understanding this, though. Is that right? What does it being a pronoun have to do with the difference between: “I gave him the book...” and “I gave the book...to him”?

Comment: *I gave him the book to read* not *I gave the book him to read*.  **pronominalised** must mean "expressed as a bare pronoun (e.g. *him*)  without a preposition (e.g. *to him*)".   A dative pronoun as indirect object rather than as object of a preposition in a prepositional phrase.

Comment: So is that why he says the alternative if “Had it been a noun phrase, it would be placed after the direct object:” it would be “I gave the book to my dad.”? Is the noun phrase he’s referring to “my dad”?

Comment: I mean, noun phrase referring to “the book”. But, if that were the case, couldn’t we just say “I gave my dad the book”? That proves his logic in accurate because he claims it being a noun phrase reverses things.

Comment: Why not ask him what he meant. I've given you examples of what is permissible above. Do you have a particular sentence that's giving you difficulty, one you're trying to write?

Answer (score 0):

> **I gave dad my book**
>
> **I gave my book to dad.**
>
> **I gave him my book.**
>
> **I gave my book to him**

Although all the sentences are grammatically correct., In the first set second sentence sounds natural and in the second set the first sentence sounds natural because of the noun phrase and pronoun respectively.