# Shouldn’t “speed the development” be “speed up the development”?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Identifying such blood markers, scientists say, will improve existing vaccines and **speed the development of new ones** by reducing the need for costly large-scale efficacy trials.

Source: [Nature:   Scientists identify long-sought marker for COVID vaccine success](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01778-2)

Is the word speed in the phrase "speed the development of new ones" a formal usage in this sense? It seems to me that the formal form should have been "speed up": "speed up the development of new ones." Am I on the right track?

The problem for this question is that the speaker dropped "up" altogether while we know the combination of "speed" and "up" (no matter how far they are separated they must appear in the same sentence together) is a norm. I wonder whether this dropping "up" is grammatical.

Comment: If there's a regular verb and a phrasal verb that mean the same thing, in almost every case, the phrasal verb will be used in spoken and casual situations, while the regular verb will be used in writing and formal situations. This is an example of that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "speed up something" and "speed something up"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37403/difference-between-speed-up-something-and-speed-something-up)

Comment: @mdewey: I am sorry. No. Because that answer had pointed out that the combination of  the "main verb" and "prepositional particle" to be a necessity in the grammar, all the while in the OP the speak dropped the "prepositional particle"("up") downright, which, I suspect, has made the sentence ungrammatical. Hence the thread.

Comment: This is grammatical. You can use **speed something** or **speed up something**. Both are fine for written language.

Comment: The linked question does not deal with "speed" without "up" only with the position of "up" in the phrase or sentence. It is not even close to a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "speed" here means "hasten" or "speed up". I believe that it is an older form, now more used in formal situations, and more common in UK English than US English at this time.  There is no significant difference in meaning in this case.

"Speed" in this sense is used in several stock phrases:

> - To speed the parting guest. (To hasten a guest into leaving, or help a guest on his or her way.)
> - To speed the plow. (To encourage agriculture, or help farmers generally.)
> - To speed the night. (To make the night pass more quickly or seem to.)
> - To speed his journey. (To help him make the trip faster.)